# Creating time series of NDVI data using Landsat 8 imagery

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series, landtrendr

I am trying to calculate the average annual NDVI of Landsat imagery on a forest in Kentucky. The study will occur from 1984-2020. I am writing code specifically for Landsat 8 at the moment, but I plan to replicate the code for Landsats 5 and 7 so I can cover the entire study period. I am having issues with calculating NDVI. I keep receiving an error message that says,

> "Line 34: Cannot read property 'normalizedDifference' of undefined"

I have included the code below. The image collections I am using are LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2, LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2, and LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2. The variables used in this line are already defined, so I am not sure why I am getting an error about an undefined piece of information. What is the issue with line 34?

```
////  NDVI Trend Analysis using Landsat 5, 7, & 8:

////  Study area: Berea College Forest
////  Shapfile imported as "BCF"

////  Years to process by satellite:
var yearsL5 = [1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998];
var yearsL7 = [1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012];
var yearsL8 = [2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020];

var display_min = 0;  ////  What do these two lines do?
var display_max = 100;

//Julian dates of study period
var start_day = 105;  //  Apr 15
var end_day = 288;    //  Oct 15

////  Number of years for each image:
var year_space = 1;

////  Create day filter and a simple
////  composite using Earth Engine's built-in algorithm:
var quick_L8 = function(year){
    var result = ee.ImageCollection(L8)
    .filterDate(new Date(year, 1,1), new Date(year + year_space-1, 12,31))  //// What does this line do?
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start_day, end_day)).filterBounds(BCF);
};

////  Create index with 1/1/year time stamp:
var create_index_w_time_stamp = function(year){
    var ls = quick_L8(year);
    var time_start = new Date(year, 1, 1);
    var time_end = new Date(year + 1, 1, 1);
    var NDVI = quick_L8(year).normalizedDifference(['SR_B5','SR_B4']).setMulti({'system:time_start': time_start.valueOf(),'system:time_end': time_end.valueOf()});
    return NDVI;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////  Finalize processing:

var ndvi_collection = ee.ImageCollection(yearsL8.map(create_index_w_time_stamp));
//print(ndvi_collection);
var trends = ndvi_collection.formaTrend();
Map.addLayer(ndvi_collection);
var SAMpalette = ['00ff00','008000', '808000', 'ffff00','ffA500', 'ff0000','800000','8c2a04'];
SAMpalette.reverse();

Map.addLayer(trends, {bands:'long-trend', min: -0.1, max: 0.1, palette:SAMpalette}, 'Long term trend');

////  Further diagnostics:
//print(trends);

var sfTimeSeries =
  UI.Chart.image.series(ndvi_collection, BCF, ee.Reducer.mean(), 200);

////  Visualize time series in the Console:
print(sfTimeSeries, 'LineChart');


////  Zoom to BCF and add shapefile
Map.setCenter(-84.2357424, 37.5394361, 12);
Map.addLayer(BCF, {}, 'Berea College Forest');
```

Comment: Which line is line 34?

Comment: The error tells you exactly what your problem is. In line 34 you are trying to access a property normalizedDifference of object that is not defined or undefined. But in order to tell you what is going wrong you probably have to organize a reproducable example that shows the error when we run the script